# How to launch an external Process?

Tags: swift, macos, process

I am reading through the docs of swift and came across Type Methods. For example here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process

The offered Type Method is:

`class func run(URL, arguments: [String], terminationHandler: ((Process) -> Void)? = nil)`

How can I use this in my code? For example when I press a button? How can I add a clean-up function to the terminationHandler?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a `macos` app, you may use `run` for launching external processes, an example might be:

1) one-shot execution:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/bin/ls")
do {
   try Process.run(url, arguments: []) { (process) in
      print("\ndidFinish: \(!process.isRunning)")
   }
} catch {}
```

---

2)  you may want to use a `Process` instance to be able to setup more comfortably its behaviour, doing so:

```
let process = Process()
process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/bin/ls")
process.arguments = ["-la"]
process.terminationHandler = { (process) in
   print("\ndidFinish: \(!process.isRunning)")
}
do {
  try process.run()
} catch {}
```

So I did launch the `ls` command (you may check your console for the result), then in the closure `terminationHandler` I'm getting back such process.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Quick follow up. If I declare everything by hand like
`let process = Process ()` and then want to use the terminational handler by invoking `var terminationHandler: ((Process) -> Void)?` how would the syntax look like for this closure? Is it even a closure? I am new to swift and all is still confusing.

Comment: You are welcome. I added an edit related to your question.

Comment: I get "createProcess: runInteractiveProcess: exec: permission denied (Operation not permitted)", which entitlement do I need to set to give permission for my app?