# How to include an external executable into a MacOS app?

Tags: swift, nstask

I am building a simple app with a `TextField` input.
I want to pass the input of the `TextField` to a cli tool I built with Golang.

This cli-tool is not sitting in `/usr/bin` but under `~/go/bin` in my user directory.
So, when I try something like the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726436/how-to-execute-external-program-from-swift) it's not able to find the executable.

I tried copying the executable in every single folder of the Application but I am still getting the same error.

Where exactly am I supposed to copy the executable?
What does the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25729093/8901937) looks like after I copied it over?

Comment: @matt are you sure it's the right link? I don't see any mention about PATH there. The problem comes with executables outside of `/usr/bin`. If I pass in `/usr/bin/ls` for example everything is fine. But if I instead pass `/Users/John/go/bin/myclitool` that doesn't work

Comment: Are you sandboxed?

Comment: Yes, I am running sandboxed. I want to bundle the executable into the app

Comment: You do? Then why are we talking about /usr/bin and things like that???

Comment: Because if I execute commands from `/usr/bin` or for instance `/bin/pwd`, no complains. But if I point to my local executable `/Users/John/bin/myclitool` it complains

Comment: But if you're going to include the tool in your app bundle, it won't be in _any_ of those places. So who cares which of them it works in and which of them it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference this worked:

Step 1: embed the binary in the build ([Adding resource files to xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247680/adding-resource-files-to-xcode)). To open the project tab just double click on your app root in XCode

Step 2: You will find the path to your executable like this:

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
let pathToExecutable = bundle.url(forResource: "myclitool", withExtension: "")
```

and then you can use `Process` to run it (e.g. [How to launch an external Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48333607/how-to-launch-an-external-process))

Answer (score 0):

[Apple provides documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/embedding-a-helper-tool-in-a-sandboxed-app#Create-the-app-project) for this very thing.

Bouncing off @gallivantingitalian 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71810629/388983) you may find the `Bundle.main.url(forAuxiliaryExecutable:)` command helpful if following Apple’s documentation.

```
let process = Process()
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forAuxiliaryExecutable: "my_awesome_tool") else {
    throw AppErrors.appConfigError(reason: "my_awesome_tool tool not found")
}
process.executableURL = url
```